# Load other views in secondary thread Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

in my program I use a FlipView taken from a library (https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView). This component use a Base Adapter to create some views with flip effect between them. The component load the first two views, that are very fast, but from the third the effect becomes very slow. I wanted to know if there is a method to retrieve the getView() to load the other pages in a parallel thread. In this way I could create the first two views and automatically, as they are viewed, load the other.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All UI loads and alternates only by UI thread which is main. You can try to rebuild FlipView to do some part of its job in asynctask